# Laravel Eloquent ORM eager loading. Relation incorrectly returned as null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have an Eloquent ORM relationship defined as follows:

**ProductConfiguration**:

```
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Excel\Products\Product');
    }

    public function currency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Excel\Currencies\Currency');
    }
```

**Product**

```
    public function productConfigurations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Excel\Products\ProductConfiguration');
    }
    public function productType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Excel\Products\ProductType');
    }
```

I expect that if I do the following that I will load all product configurations of a specified product type, with the related products, nested product type details and the product configuration currency

```
$results = ProductConfiguration::with(
            array(
                'product' => function($query) use ($product_type) {
                        $query->where('product_type_id' , $product_type);
                    },
                'product.productType',
                'currency'
            )
        )


            ->get();
```

however the returned collection has 'product' set to NULL. the Currency Relationship is there, but the product relationship is not. I can see the outputted SQL queries and the query that selects the products retrieves the correct products if I paste it directly into my sql editor

```
select * from `products` 
where `products`.`id` in ('12', '13') 
and `product_type_id` = '1'
```

Am I correct to think that the results from this query should be included in my collection, or is there some obvious flaw in my thinking?

Comment: What happen if you remove ```'product.productType'``` and add this to you're ```'product'``` function: ```$query->with('productType')```? Hope that helps.

Comment: Same result. Product is NULL. Its bizarre, because the correct SQL quries are being run, but the results are not appearing in the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't want to achieve that. Now what you get is getting all `ProductConfiguration` with `products` that are only of `certain_type`.

So in case you have some configuration that has other type for `product` you will get null because you limited results from `product` to only the one that has certain product type.

I might be wrong, but you probably wanted to get those `ProductConfiguration` that belongs to `Product` that is type of `certain_type`. In this case you should use `whereHas`:

```
$results = ProductConfiguration::
          with('product', 'product.productType', 'currency')->
          whereHas('product', function($q) use ($product_type)
          {
            $q->where('product_type_id', '=', $product_type);

          })->get();
```

Comment: Well spotted. Much more efficient query

Answer (score 1):

I hate to post this as an answer but since i don't have enough rep to comment so try this first:

```
$results = ProductConfiguration::with('product')->get();

dd($results->toArray());
```

See what you get, if you get some data, try this

```
$results = ProductConfiguartion::with(array('products' => function($query){
    $query->where('product_type_id' , $product_type);
})->get();

dd($results);
```

See what you get, if you get null: your $product_type variable may be something you didnt expect, so try dd($product_type) to make sure its what your expecting.

Comment: good trouble shooting technique. I must have had some sort of caching issue, because I broke it down into the steps you outlined and it worked. I put back in the stripped out parts bit by bit until I was left with my original query and it stayed working.